# Visual Studio C# Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt

Tags: c#, emgucv, face-detection, face-recognition

I am creating an Attendance System using 4 cameras for facial recognition. I am using Emgu CV 3.0 in C#. Now, in my attendance form, which consist of 4 imagebox, the application suddenly stops and it goes back to the main form and shows an error to the button which reference the attendance form. The error was:

Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

Here is the code where the error occured:

```
    private void btn_attendance_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        attendance attendance = new attendance();
        attendance.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Here is the code for the Attendance form without the recognition part:

```
public partial class attendance : Form
{
    private Capture cam1, cam2, cam3, cam4;
    private CascadeClassifier _cascadeClassifier;
    private RecognizerEngine _recognizerEngine;
    private String _trainerDataPath = "\\traineddata_v2";
    private readonly String dbpath = "Server=localhost;Database=faculty_attendance_system;Uid=root;Pwd=root;";
    MySqlConnection conn;

    public attendance()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
        conn = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=faculty_attendance_system;Uid=root;Pwd=root;");
    }

    private void btn_home_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void attendance_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        time_now.Start();
        lbl_date.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("");
        _recognizerEngine = new RecognizerEngine(dbpath, _trainerDataPath);

        _cascadeClassifier = new CascadeClassifier(Application.StartupPath + "/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml");
        cam1 = new Capture(0);
        cam2 = new Capture(1);
        cam3 = new Capture(3);
        cam4 = new Capture(4);

        Application.Idle += new EventHandler(ProcessFrame);
    }

    private void ProcessFrame(Object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        Image<Bgr, byte> nextFrame_cam1 = cam1.QueryFrame().ToImage<Bgr, Byte>();
        Image<Bgr, byte> nextFrame_cam2 = cam2.QueryFrame().ToImage<Bgr, Byte>();
        Image<Bgr, byte> nextFrame_cam3 = cam3.QueryFrame().ToImage<Bgr, Byte>();
        Image<Bgr, byte> nextFrame_cam4 = cam4.QueryFrame().ToImage<Bgr, Byte>();

        using (nextFrame_cam1)
        {
           if (nextFrame_cam1 != null)
            {
                Image<Gray, byte> grayframe = nextFrame_cam1.Convert<Gray, byte>();
                var faces = _cascadeClassifier.DetectMultiScale(grayframe, 1.5, 10, Size.Empty, Size.Empty);
                foreach (var face in faces)
                {
                    nextFrame_cam1.Draw(face, new Bgr(Color.Green), 3);
                    var predictedUserId = _recognizerEngine.RecognizeUser(new Image<Gray, byte>(nextFrame_cam1.Bitmap));
                }
                imageBox1.Image = nextFrame_cam1;
            }
        }

        using (nextFrame_cam2)
        {
           if (nextFrame_cam2!= null)
            {
                Image<Gray, byte> grayframe = nextFrame_cam2.Convert<Gray, byte>();
                var faces = _cascadeClassifier.DetectMultiScale(grayframe, 1.5, 10, Size.Empty, Size.Empty);
                foreach (var face in faces)
                {
                    nextFrame_cam2.Draw(face, new Bgr(Color.Green), 3);
                    var predictedUserId = _recognizerEngine.RecognizeUser(new Image<Gray, byte>(nextFrame_cam2.Bitmap));
                }
                imageBox2.Image = nextFrame_cam2;
            }
        }


        using (nextFrame_cam3)
        {
           if (nextFrame_cam3!= null)
            {
                Image<Gray, byte> grayframe = nextFrame_cam3.Convert<Gray, byte>();
                var faces = _cascadeClassifier.DetectMultiScale(grayframe, 1.5, 10, Size.Empty, Size.Empty);
                foreach (var face in faces)
                {
                    nextFrame_cam3.Draw(face, new Bgr(Color.Green), 3);
                    var predictedUserId = _recognizerEngine.RecognizeUser(new Image<Gray, byte>(nextFrame_cam3.Bitmap));
                }
                imageBox3.Image = nextFrame_cam3;
            }
        }

        using (nextFrame_cam4)
        {
           if (nextFrame_cam4!= null)
            {
                Image<Gray, byte> grayframe = nextFrame_cam4.Convert<Gray, byte>();
                var faces = _cascadeClassifier.DetectMultiScale(grayframe, 1.5, 10, Size.Empty, Size.Empty);
                foreach (var face in faces)
                {
                    nextFrame_cam4.Draw(face, new Bgr(Color.Green), 3);
                    var predictedUserId = _recognizerEngine.RecognizeUser(new Image<Gray, byte>(nextFrame_cam4.Bitmap));
                }
                imageBox4.Image = nextFrame_cam4;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So use the debugger and step through the code to figure out where the problem is actually located. We can't do that for you; we don't have all of your code and project files and references.

Answer (score 1):

Plz read this post to know what is memory leakage.
http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/625/best-practices-no-5-detecting-net-application-memory-leaks

Your error indicate that you are creating many instances of a class or any recursive call of function.
Use Using() to create object of Emgu so that as soon as your code terminate the managed or unmanaged memory will be disposed.

```
public partial class attendance : Form
{
    private Capture cam1, cam2, cam3, cam4;
    private CascadeClassifier _cascadeClassifier;
    private RecognizerEngine _recognizerEngine;
    private String _trainerDataPath = "\\traineddata_v2";
    private readonly String dbpath = "Server=localhost;Database=faculty_attendance_system;Uid=root;Pwd=root;";
    MySqlConnection conn;

    public attendance()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        conn = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=faculty_attendance_system;Uid=root;Pwd=root;");
    }

    private void btn_home_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
    private void attendance_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        time_now.Start();
        lbl_date.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("");
        _recognizerEngine = new RecognizerEngine(dbpath, _trainerDataPath);
        _cascadeClassifier = new CascadeClassifier(Application.StartupPath + "/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml");
        cam1 = new Capture(0);
        cam2 = new Capture(1);
        cam3 = new Capture(3);
        cam4 = new Capture(4);
        Application.Idle += new EventHandler(ProcessFrame);
    }
    private void ProcessFrame(Object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        using (Image<Bgr, byte> nextFrame_cam1 = cam1.QueryFrame().ToImage<Bgr, Byte>())
        {
            if (nextFrame_cam1 != null)
            {
                Image<Gray, byte> grayframe = nextFrame_cam1.Convert<Gray, byte>();
                var faces = _cascadeClassifier.DetectMultiScale(grayframe, 1.5, 10, Size.Empty, Size.Empty);
                foreach (var face in faces)
                {
                    nextFrame_cam1.Draw(face, new Bgr(Color.Green), 3);
                    var predictedUserId = _recognizerEngine.RecognizeUser(new Image<Gray, byte>(nextFrame_cam1.Bitmap));
                }
                imageBox1.Image = nextFrame_cam1;
            }
        }

        using (Image<Bgr, byte> nextFrame_cam2 = cam2.QueryFrame().ToImage<Bgr, Byte>())
        {
            if (nextFrame_cam2 != null)
            {
                Image<Gray, byte> grayframe = nextFrame_cam2.Convert<Gray, byte>();
                var faces = _cascadeClassifier.DetectMultiScale(grayframe, 1.5, 10, Size.Empty, Size.Empty);
                foreach (var face in faces)
                {
                    nextFrame_cam2.Draw(face, new Bgr(Color.Green), 3);
                    var predictedUserId = _recognizerEngine.RecognizeUser(new Image<Gray, byte>(nextFrame_cam2.Bitmap));
                }
                imageBox2.Image = nextFrame_cam2;
            }
        }


        using (Image<Bgr, byte> nextFrame_cam3 = cam3.QueryFrame().ToImage<Bgr, Byte>())
        {
            if (nextFrame_cam3 != null)
            {
                Image<Gray, byte> grayframe = nextFrame_cam3.Convert<Gray, byte>();
                var faces = _cascadeClassifier.DetectMultiScale(grayframe, 1.5, 10, Size.Empty, Size.Empty);
                foreach (var face in faces)
                {
                    nextFrame_cam3.Draw(face, new Bgr(Color.Green), 3);
                    var predictedUserId = _recognizerEngine.RecognizeUser(new Image<Gray, byte>(nextFrame_cam3.Bitmap));
                }
                imageBox3.Image = nextFrame_cam3;
            }
        }

        using (Image<Bgr, byte> nextFrame_cam4 = cam4.QueryFrame().ToImage<Bgr, Byte>())
        {
            if (nextFrame_cam4 != null)
            {
                Image<Gray, byte> grayframe = nextFrame_cam4.Convert<Gray, byte>();
                var faces = _cascadeClassifier.DetectMultiScale(grayframe, 1.5, 10, Size.Empty, Size.Empty);
                foreach (var face in faces)
                {
                    nextFrame_cam4.Draw(face, new Bgr(Color.Green), 3);
                    var predictedUserId = _recognizerEngine.RecognizeUser(new Image<Gray, byte>(nextFrame_cam4.Bitmap));
                }
                imageBox4.Image = nextFrame_cam4;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Plz fowllow this document for standard way to work with EMGU.CV  for face recongnization.
http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Face_detection

Comment: Welcome to SO. If it is possible, it would be best to quote the most important parts from your links (while keeping the link as a reference). That way your answer won't become outdated in the years to come. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @LonelyNeuron